# Google Chrome-like tab behavior in Opera

Tags: google-chrome, opera, browser-tabs

How can I have Google Chrome-like tab behavior in Opera?

In Opera, when I open some links in background tab and then close the current tab, it just goes to the left tab.

Update: Google Chrome tab behavior

Google Chrome tabs work in a way that I don't have to open new window or move tabs while I just browse the web and open a lot of links in background tabs and then in each of those link, open another set of links in background and so on.

After some testing with reddit pages, here's how I think Google Chrome tabs work:

- Open a bunch of links (from the same
  page) in background tabs, where are
  the new tabs?  The new tabs are
  immediately to the right (of the
  opener tab).
- Close a tab, then which tab is
  activated/focused? A sibling tab (of
  the closed tab) is closed, if it
  exists. (Tab X is a sibling of tab Y
  if X and Y have the same parent tab
  Z. Tab Z is the parent of tab X if X
  is opened from Z.) If you close tabs
  successively, sibling tabs to the
  right are closed (because they the
  ones being focused after each
  closing) and then the sibling tabs to
  the left are closed, and then the
  focus is on the parent tab, which is usually immediately to the left of the last closed tab. It
  doesn't work this way if you move
  tabs around.

Also see [tabbed browsing in Google Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/01/tabbed-browsing-in-google-chrome.html)

Comment: For those of us who never really used chrome, define "Chrome-like" behaviour :)

Comment: Added my guess on Chrome-like behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: When closing a tab]

Comment: I miss the old Opera that was built with Presto instead of Webkit and Chromium.

Answer (score -1):

Today, on Opera 65.0.3467.48, you will use the option below.

Opera 65.0.3467.48 cycle tab settings

[image: Opera 65.0.3467.48 cycle tab settings]